# How to convert automatically $10k to 10000 in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How to covert 10k to 10000 in SQL query

Comment: What did you try so far and what was wrong with your code

Answer (score 3):

Use REPLACE

```
SELECT  REPLACE('$10k', 'k', '000')
```

Returns

```
REPLACE('$10k', 'k', '000')
'$10000'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this - it's pretty foolproof:

```
WITH                                                                                                                                                        
indata(amount) AS (
            SELECT '10000' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT '10k'   FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT '200'   FROM dual
)
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN LOWER(amount) LIKE '%k'
    THEN CAST(RTRIM(LOWER(amount),'k') AS NUMBER(9,0)) * 1000
    ELSE CAST(AMOUNT AS NUMBER(9,0))
  END AS numeric_amount
FROM indata
-- out  numeric_amount 
-- out ----------------
-- out           10000
-- out           10000
-- out             200
```